# Regex to remove unwanted space between unique characters

Tags: javascript, regex

We are using an OCR to extract text from images. One of my most annoying problems from this OCR, is that I got sometime unwanted space, because the OCR found a word which was with a big tracking between characters.

For example I got:

```
var text = "CHA BLIS 1 ER CRU CONTROLEEC B E A U R O Y C a Chablisienne"
```

I tried to do:

```
test.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z]\b)/, '$1')
```

But if I do so, I got as results:

```
CHA BLIS 1 ER CRU CONTROLEECBEAUROYC a Chablisienne
```

But expected results should be:

```
CHA BLIS 1 ER CRU CONTROLEEC BEAUROYCa Chablisienne
```

My absolute need is to regroup single character all together but, not to change other words.

If:

```
var text = "CHA BLIS 1 ER CRU CONTROLEEC BEAU R O Y C a Chablisienne"
```

It should output:

```
CHA BLIS 1 ER CRU CONTROLEEC BEAU ROYCa Chablisienne
```

I didn't succeed yet after hours spent to found the right combination.

ps : no difference of treatment has to be done between upper and lowercase.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how uppercase vs lowercase single letters should be treated?

Comment: There is no difference of process/treatment between upper and lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to stick all single separated letters together:

```
\b([A-Za-z])\s+(?!\w\B)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP1vV7/3)

Otherwise use a single `\b` word boundary token:

```
\b([A-Z])\s+(?![^A-Z])
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP1vV7/4)

Answer (score 0):

Using [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), you can limit the search to single characters:

```
test.replace(/\b([A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]\b)/i, '$1')
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qB6cU6/1).

Comment: @revo: Why, in your opinion?

Comment: That time I didn't have a close look at expected output where a majuscule could see a minuscule. So your answer is valid.